# Disappearing spaces between words

Tags: html, css, space

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><HTML><HEAD><style>
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
    font-size: 12pt;
}
</style>
</HEAD><BODY> Особенно часто такие ситуации возникают при попытках реализовать программно полет мысли дизайнера с учетом технических особенностей таких систем.
</br>
О том, как мы решаем такие задачи при работе над мобильным приложением xxx, мы расскажем в этой статье.</BODY></HTML>
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the spaces in the second sentence (please look at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qx7NY/3/)?

Here is what the browser shows me:

[image]

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: I don't see any problems.

Comment: Interesting. Changing the font solves the problem here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman if I remove all the spaces in second sentence and then type them again - all getting looks fine as it should be

Comment: @PatrickHofman what does it means "not support Russian characters"? How do you think Apple localizes the iOS7, which has helvetica neue almost everywhere

Comment: and `<br/>` not `</br>`  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inspected that code block (with Chrome's inspector) and saw this:

[image: screenshot]

You used thin spaces (`&thinsp;` or  ) instead of normal spaces (). I have no idea where you got them, but apparently the font you're using doesn't support thin spaces, so they don't show up.

Simply change all the  s (thin spaces) into normal spaces, and it will work fine. (Or use a find/replace tool.)

Answer (score 0):

it's not any spaces in second sentence! you can type this sentence.

or

remove web copy format:

1. copy the sentence
2. paste in notepad
3. copy sentence again

Answer (score -1):

Use `<pre>` tag to preserve spaces,

[image]
Take a look at this,
http://jsfiddle.net/qx7NY/10/

Comment: what about line breaking? perhaps I need to squeeze my <body> by width:320px;

Comment: Its a pre tag you can have breaks anywhere you want, and those white spaces will be preserved, http://jsfiddle.net/qx7NY/12/ . Well he wanted spaces, and this approach shows even the thin spaces properly.